# How to get feature info from wms layer

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have used your code for picking feature info from WMS layer using WMSGetFeatureInfo function. I have used this link.
http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/picking-a-features-attribute-value-from-a-wms-layer-with-openlayers/
but I can't find the feature info.

feature.length function returns 0.

My WMS layer is:

```
 tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
                    "unit_project2_ws:unit_project3_view - Tiled", 
                    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/unit_project2_ws/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'unit_project2_ws:unit_project3',
                        transparent: true,
                        STYLES: '',
                        format: format,
                        tiled: true,
                        tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom

                    },
                    {
                        buffer: 0,
                        displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                        isBaseLayer: false,
                        yx : {'EPSG:900913' : false}
                    } 
                );
```

........................

Code I have used for the GetFeatureInfo request for the WMS layer:

```
roadidPicker = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/unit_project2_ws/wms',>
                title: 'identify features on click',
                layers: [tiled],
                queryVisible: true
            });
roadidPicker.infoFormat = 'application/vnd.ogc.gml';
roadidPicker.events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, pickRoadid);
map.addControl(roadidPicker);
roadidPicker.activate();

function pickRoadid(e) {
  if (e.features && e.features.length) {
     var val = e.features[0].attributes.id;
     alert(val);
     //document.getElementById('roadId').value = val;
  }
  else
      alert(e.features.length);  // this function returns 0 result.

}
```

What is problem with this code.

Comment: Can u please provide the working code...

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of those html 
 tags in your code. I really do not know if that is your problem but I have never seen that.

Comment: oh,sory,tags have been removed now,that was my negligency,Problem is code else than html tags,Now check the code and answer me.

Comment: I dropped the WMSGetFeatureInfo code and the pickRoadid function into a map and they worked for me on a wms layer. I had a featurelength. What happens when you change your url to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms'?